# Exact Target - Data Integration

Tags: marketing-cloud

[image]Hello I am looking for solutions to export data from Exact Target which would eventually be fed into a dashboarding tool. Here are the set of questions that I have related to this data integration:[image]

1. I would like to capture - List of all the emails sent for the accounts, • Time Sent 
   Unique Opens Total Opens, Unique Clicks, Total Clicks,Delivered Rate,Hard Bounce Rate,Soft Bounce Rate,Block Bounce Rate,Links Clicked,Unsubscribes. I know there are a bunch of reports that provide Email summary in the Email Studio reports, the closest I got was when I ran the report called 'Recent Email Sending Summary' but only got few metrics, not all metrics are available. Is there a better way to capture these metrics using Email Studio or any other means and to build a report out of it ?
2. Once I get these metrics, I need to send the above reports as attachments via recurring emails, say for example emails with .csv attachments containing metrics are sent every week/month in an automated manner from exact target.Any way to achieve this ?
3. I cam across few ways, like Data EXtraction uploading file to FTP but it has a limit of just 30 days or so since I want all data until now. Also, looked at Query in Exact Target but it again has a data limit of upto 60 days. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I had worked on similar request, but capture was limited to few activities. I had used Data Extract activity extract type was: Tracking Extract. yes the extract period is limited for 30 day window but you can create multiple extract activities for specific rolling range.

Example: if you want to pull all the data from Jan 2017 till date, we can create one data extract for each month. you can select rolling range for each month
Jan : 1/1/2017 to 1/30/2017
Feb: 1/31/2017 to 2/28/2017  so on.. 
each data extract will produce one zip file of report.

These are some of the options available in tracking extract that corresponds to data you need

1. List of all the emails sent for the accounts - Extract Send Job Option (you can see CLientID,SendID,EmailName,SentTime etc..)
2. Time Sent --  This field is obtained from Extract Send Job Option (SentTime)
3. Unique Opens-- Include Unique Opens Option
4. Total Opens -- Extract Opens Option
5. Unique Clicks-- Include Unique Clicks option
6. Total Clicks -- Extract Clicks Option
7. Delivered Rate -- Not sure
8. Hard Bounce Rate  - Extract Bounce option ( Bounce Category shows the type of bounce)
9. Soft Bounce Rate - Extract Bounce option ( Bounce Category shows the type of bounce)
10. Block Bounce Rate - Extract Bounce option ( Bounce Category shows the type of bounce)
11. Links Clicked -- In the Extract Clicks Option you have the field URL it shows the link clicked by particluar subscriber for particular send
12. Unsubscribes.  -- Extract Unsubs option and Include Unsub Reason Option

Sample data extract configuration

[image]

[image]

The resulting extract file can be transferred to desired ftp location.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion. Can this step of creating multiple instances of activities be automated or it has to be down manually for every month that you want to track ? Also I believe this whole process can be setup as a program and scheduled to run on a timely basis ? Thanks !

Comment: yes  each data extract activity has to be configured manually, this works if you are trying to fetch data from previous months till date in case you had not captured it.this is solution for a one time thing.Moving forward if you want to automate this process  select the option "Rolling Range" instead of "Specific Range" and set it to 1 week and schedule your automation to run weekly, by this way at the end of the week you will have the extracts for all the sends of the week, once set you need not do anything manually. in automation step 1: data extract step 2: file transfer activity.

Comment: thank you so much for all the information ! I tried to test this by creating a data extract activity for getting data for past 7 days and then created a file transfer activity for it. Then ran both respectively but when I check my FTP server for any uploads I do not see any file. I have attached the images of my configuration for both data extract and file transfer in my original post above, can you let me know if anything looks off ? Thanks !

Comment: just to let you know I have not done or created any other steps apart from creating a data extract activity and file transfer activity and starting them by hitting the start button. Thanks

Comment: screenshots attached in the original post above

Comment: okay so the problem is in your FTP, the file location you have chosen is safehouse, We use Safehouse location when we want to Import/Export  files from marketing cloud without the files being transferred to Enhanced FTP site directories and this location is a centralized storage and can be accessed by authenticated users.Please use Export folder as of now

Comment: Also, please run these activities in automation studio, so that you will get to know in case it failed, one more point on the file naming pattern is i had used this tar.gz format.. so "test.tar.gz" this results in  a compressed folder which contains csv file for each activity and you can extract this the normal way as you would do with a zip file. I have attached the screenshot of how that folder looks ( in answer section)

Comment: Thank you ! I see the zip file now in FTP when I changed the transfer target to Enhanced FTP. Is there a way to get all the data in a single excel sheet rather than having multiple multiple excel files exported ? In my test case, this would be beneficial only if all data appears in a single excel file. Thanks !

Comment: Sorry, i am aware of only this method.. but its not like all the files are exported individually to ftp it is still in one compressed folder as i have shown in the screenshot right? i feel easy to differentiate each activity  given separate file for each, all enclosed in one folder.